# Multiple Image Viewer w/ thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a simple multiple image viewer for my website and i found a create resource for the code:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-multiple-image-viewer-thumbnails/

however, i would like the image to switch on "mouseover" and when clicked i would like it to go to another website, so working from this code:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="switch_product_img('photo_1', 3);"><img src="ARTofWAR_BLK(3).jpg" alt="Black" /></a></li>
```

do i strip the javascript from the < a > tag and add it into the < img > tag? i am a newbie when it comes to javascript so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="ARTofWAR_BLK(3).jpg" alt="Black" onmouseover="switch_product_img('photo_1', 3);"/>
    </a>
 </li>
```